# Write to file and then send it via api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a retrieve api which receives a pk and then i want to:

1. retrieve from database the record
2. Create a file from a Binary column
3. Send back the file that is created.

So i have the following code which works, but i am not sure if its the best way, because i am creating the file and then i am going back to the file system in order to retrieve it with widget_bundle = open(test+'.js', 'rb'). Is there a better way to send it as i have it and not read it again?.

```
 def retrieve(self, request, pk):

    try:
        ts = Test.objects.get(code=pk)
    except Test.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    with open(ts.code+'.js', 'w') as filetowrite:
        filetowrite.write(str(bytes(ts.data), 'utf-8'))

    try:
        file = open(ts.code+'.js', 'rb')
    except Exception as e:
        pass

    response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(file),
                            content_type='application/javascript')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: yes, just send ts.data in the response and set a few response headers to inform the browser that this is a file and what the filename is:

```
response = HttpResponse(ts.data, content_type='application/javascript')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=ts.code + ".js"'
```

As seen here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment

By the way, if you do it this way, there is no reason to write or read from a file at all.  Unless there is more to your application that necessitates having this file on your server for some reason.

### Security

I notice you are creating a file based on database contents alone.  If somewhere else in your app you've allowed your mischevious users to set the name and contents, then you will have a security hole.  particularly if you are not careful about where files can go if people use path names in that filename field.  At the very least, you probably want to watch out for: 1) make sure you limit the size they can put in your db and serve and 2) make sure there's no way to break out of the temporary directory you intend to write these temporary files too for serving

### Efficiency

More efficient in all this, would be to return a HttpRedirect response instead of content.  Write the temp file and then return a redirect to a valid URL that will trigger "someone else" to actually serve that file.  Make the "someone else" be your web server (e.g. nginx) and configure a special path in your web server that knows that this means we're going to go get files from our temporary file holding area.

If you do all that, you will also need to consider whether you want to add some access control to those files, if for some reason you want to make it more difficult for arbitrary people to download other peoples files just by guessing the URL.

**Or, forget the file stuff but add caching**

Alternatively, if you decide to stop writing to disk completely, an efficiency boost would be to implement caching and wrap this function with a cache decorator. Once caching is configured, you'll just put *cache_page* on your request function with some cache time (15 minutes in this example), like this:

```
@cache_page(60 * 15)
def retrieve(self, request, pk):
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/

Caching might be a good idea here, since you are talking about a potentially-large database request.

### Another small gotcha

I see nothing here to guarantee unique filenames.  If two different records, different people, have same filename, will someone get confusing results? Probably.  You might want to segment by username or something. Or generate unique filenames.

Comment: Yes my mistake. I edit the answer and made it ts.data

Comment: Does the answer satisfy your question now?